# What are the possible way to cache static assets in web application?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, browser, client

I want to cache static assets of my web application for performance improvement. 
Now I have add **Cache-Control** header to cache that. I want to know about different caching mechanism of web application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just use ServiceWorker. It is one way to cache everything you need.

Comment: Do you know any other way? Because, I want cache files to cross browsers. Service worker only support Chrome and Firefox.